# Is it possible to "mount" a shared folder as subdirectory in my Dropbox account?

Tags: dropbox

Example:

I have a dropbox with several folders. One of these folders is called "shared-to-me". My friend, Fred shared his "party-videos" folder to me. I want to "mount" this inside my "shared-to-me" folder. So folder structure on my dropbox will be:

- root folder

  - shared-to-me

    - party-videos

Is this possible? If yes, how? I've looked around and I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just join the shared folder and then move it into your "shared-to-me" folder. Dropbox says:

> You can rename or move your shared folders just like you would any
>   other folder on your hard drive or via the website. Even if you rename
>   it, the folder will still remain shared.

https://www.dropbox.com/help/64

Comment: seems to me it's a step for "Fred" and not something I can do.

Comment: @mrjayviper: No, the name and location certainly are individual to each account.